# Trying to use a toggle button in excel to hide/unhide certain columns, columns are not adjacent though

Tags: excel, vba, togglebutton

Hi i am trying to use a toggle button in excel to hide/unhide certain columns, columns are not adjacent though and i cannot seem to get it working. I am using the below currently which works but soon as i add in a range it throws an error.

This works below

```
Private Sub ShowBarclaysColumns_Click()
xAddress = "A:C"
If ShowBarclaysColumns.Value Then
Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = True
Else
Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

but i need it to be the below and it doesn't work :(

```
Private Sub ShowBarclaysColumns_Click()
xAddress = "A:A, C:E, G:H, L:L"
If ShowBarclaysColumns.Value Then
Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = True
Else
Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Range(xAddress).EntireColumn to refer to the columns of multiple non-contiguous areas. You would write your code like so:

```
Private Sub ShowBarclaysColumns_Click()
    xAddress = "A:A, C:E, G:H, L:L"
    If ShowBarclaysColumns.Value Then
        Application.ActiveSheet.Range(xAddress).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Application.ActiveSheet.Range(xAddress).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks both, really useful!

Answer (score 0):

I fit all of my tools with a macro that does something similar, although it works slightly differently because it is a nice easily repeatable process that works for a range of criteria, and I can just keep reusing the same macro. I generally reserve Row 1 for a formula that determines if the column should be hidden or not. In the example below, Row 1 is fitted with an If formula that results in "HIDE" if you want the column hidden. Then, if Row 1 from Column A to Column EZ shows the word "HIDE", the column will be hidden.

```
        For Each c In Range("A1:EZ1").Cells
            If c.Value = "HIDE" Then
                c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next c
```